Why does Azure AI Search REST API return different indexer status than the Azure Portal?
I am using Azure AI Search.
In the Azure portal, I have an indexer with a 'Failed' status:

In my application, I retrieve the indexer's status using the following REST API call:
GET https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexers/[indexer name]/status?api-version=2024-07-01
as documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/indexers/get-status?view=rest-searchservice-2024-07-01&tabs=HTTP
I get this response:

Discrepancy: The REST API response differs from the Azure Portal's display. Specifically, as shown in my screenshot.
Question: How can I retrieve the indexer's status via the REST API to match the status displayed in the Azure Portal?
Could this be a bug in the REST API?

It is not the different result. you are checking lastresult which is success. go to execution history and check one by one. you will get correct results.

Check below solution @Allan Xu

What you are checking is lastResult which is the most recent run or in progress run will be returned.
In your case i can see it is success 2 mins ago and returned correct results via api also.
check this documentation for response definitions.
For checking all the run status, you extract executionHistory from response.
Here is sample code for it.
headers = {"Context-Type": "text/json", "api-key": "PiVvxxxxxyyyyyy"}

response = requests.get(
    url="https://<endpoint>/indexers('azureblob-indexer')/search.status?api-version=2024-07-01", headers=headers
)

for i in response.json()['executionHistory']:
    print(i['status'])

Output:

and in portal

